# new URLRequest for loading local files in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a csv file loader in an AIR project that has worked fine for a couple of years.

I browse to the required file, the listener points to the loadMyFile function, which loads the nativePath of the target file into the URLRequest, and it all loads fine - the csv file processes OK.

```
var csv:URLRequest=new URLRequest(event.target.nativePath);
```

I'd now like to set it up so the user doesn't have to browse - the file location is hard coded:

```
var csv:URLRequest=new URLRequest("C:\ProgramData\names.csv");
```

This silently fails.

If I trace the event.target.nativePath of the actual original file, it traces

```
C:\ProgramData\names.csv
```

If event.target.nativePath is just a string, any idea why hard coding in the exact same string fails?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the path because of the backslash [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) ( `\` ). So when using `C:\ProgramData\names.csv`, you are like using :

```
C:ProgramData
ames.csv
```

To more understand that take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef8.html).

So to avoid that problem, you can use double backslash ( `\\` ) in your path :

```
C:\\ProgramData\\names.csv
```

Or you can use a simple slash :

```
C:/ProgramData/names.csv
```

Hope that can help.